# mapping prop items in an array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array in which I want to loop through each element and find it's value from the props which is passed to the component.

```
array = ['a','b','c']
```

I want to save the value of 'this.props.a' to a variable 'a; and similarly for other variables considering props does have the values saved , how can I do that ?

sample code :

```
buildURL() {
    const param_array=array = ['a','b','c']
    const param_values=[];
    let queryStringUrl = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
    param_array.map((param)=>{
      param_values.push(encodeURIComponent(this.props.param)) 
    })
```

Here I need this.props.search_item , this.props.search_type , this.props.article_quality and this.props.min_views .

How can I get that?

Comment: please show more of your code.

Comment: Need more description and code in order to understand, please update the question

Comment: Seems like you're looking for something like lodash's `pick` ? https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#pick

Comment: Question updated. @Strebler , not exactly

Comment: @HimanshuJotwani, why do you want these values stored in variables in the function scope? what will you do with them then? I think if you show that then we'll be able to provide a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your code looks for `this.props.param` on each iteration of the map. Note that this does not mean it looks for the key in `props` equal to the value of `param` the variable, but looks for the key in `props` called `"param"` (equivalent to `this.props["param"]`).

To use a variable as a key in an object you need to use the brackets notation: `this.props[param]`

In your code:

```js
buildURL() {
    const param_array=['search_term','search_type','article_quality','min_views'];
    const param_values=[];
    let queryStringUrl = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
    param_array.map((param)=>{
      paramValue = this.props[param];
      param_values.push(encodeURIComponent(paramValue)) 
    })
}
```

**Edit**

To store a record of each key, value pair for those keys in `param_array` and values from `this.props`, you can create a new object in this way:

```js
buildURL() {
    const paramArray=['search_term','search_type','article_quality','min_views'];
    const paramObject = {};
    for (const param of paramArray) {
        paramObject[param] = this.props[param];
    }
    // ...
}
```

Basically, create a new, empty object (`paramObject`), then loop over each `param` in `paramArray` and assign the value for that param in the new object equal to the value for that param in `this.props`. The final object will have a key for each param in `paramArray` and values coming from `this.props`.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I store it in a variable for that block scope? Somewhat like search_term =this.props.search_term

Comment: @HimanshuJotwani I'm not sure what you mean exactly. Do you mean store the value of the prop within the `.map` scope?

Comment: Not exactly , I want to store a variable named search_term in the scope of build_url

Comment: @HimanshuJotwani if you want a variable called (exactly) `search_term`, you can just define it like `search_term = this.props.search_term;`. If you mean something more general, you can store values in an array or object, but the values here are already stored in the `props` object for you. Do you want an object that contains only the keys specified in `param_array`? What's the use case?

Comment: I want to loop through param_array , create a variable based on the values of param_array by looping and store a variable for each element of param_array with its value as this.props.variable_name

Comment: @HimanshuJotwani I made an edit to the post, does that help?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `object[property]`

```
param_array.map((param)=>{
   param_values.push(encodeURIComponent(this.props[param])) 
})
```

UPDATE:
If you want to store these into a variable, you can do it with `reduce`.

```
buildURL() {
    const param_array=['search_term','search_type','article_quality','min_views'];
    let queryStringUrl = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
    const param_values = param_array.reduce((acc, param)=>{
      acc[param]= encodeURIComponent(this.props[param])
      return acc;
    }, {})
    return param_values
}
```

Now your `param_values` is an object with the format

```
//param_values
{
  search_term: /*encoded str*/,
  search_type: /*encoded str*/,
  ...
}
```

And you can access it easily.

Comment: Could you tell me how can I store it in a variable for that block scope , somewhat like let search_term = this.props.search_term

Comment: I updated my answer. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes , kind of that but by looping through the array so that I don't have to type manually that search_term : this.props.search_term

Comment: ya. `reduce` looping too, and you don't have to type it manually. Did you read the code I updated?